# HashTable, como instanciar e inicializar

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemillas a la hora de instanciar e inicializar un HashTable. Tengo 3 clases; Tren, Vagon y Main. En la clase Tren tengo 3 bases de campo( String matrícula, String empresa y HashsetVagon), el constructor, y metodos getter y un ToString para sacar por pantalla. En la clase Vagon las base campo son(String mercancia, float toneladas) , un constructor y metodos getter y ToString.
En el main he instanciado e inicializado un Array Vagon[]vagones y un Hashsetcoleccion_vagones. Pero no sé como inicializar el HashTable (Lo he comentado porque me dá error).

El tema es que tengo que mapear (matricula, tren) y que me saque por pantalla los vagones que están enganchados en el tren con sus datos correspondientes. Me pide por pantalla una matricula y me devuelve el tren y los vagones con sus tonelada y mercancias correspondientes.
Acabo de modificar un poco el codigo que mandé por primera vez. Ahora no me sale ningún tipo de error, pero no sé como encapsular los datos de la clase Tren dentro del Hashtable.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la respuesta, sois unos cracks.

```
    package Ejercicio3;
    
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class Tren {
        
        private String matricula;
        private String empresa;
        private HashSet<Vagon>vagon=new HashSet<Vagon>();
        
        public Tren(String matricula, String empresa, HashSet<Vagon> vagon) {
            this.matricula = matricula;
            this.empresa = empresa;
            this.vagon = vagon;
        }
    
        public String getMatricula() {
            return matricula;
        }
    
        public String getEmpresa() {
            return empresa;
        }
    
        public HashSet<Vagon> getVagon() {
            return vagon;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ">DATOS TREN" + "\n" + ">EMPRESA: " + empresa + "." + "\n" + vagon + "\n" + ">FIN";
        } 
        
    }
    
   package Ejercicio3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import Ejercicio2.Registro;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        Vagon[] vagones = {
                new Vagon("Silicio",20.4f), 
                new Vagon("Silicio",20.4f), 
                new Vagon("Silicio",20.4f),                 
        };
        HashSet<Vagon> coleccion_vagones = new HashSet<Vagon>(Arrays.asList(vagones));
        
        Tren[]alta= {
                new Tren("gh-56764","ATARI",coleccion_vagones ) // aqui como inicializaria un objeto de tipo vagon dentro de un objeto tipo Tre??
        };
        
        Hashtable<String, Tren> infoTrenes = new Hashtable<String, Tren>();
        
        
        
        Set<Map.Entry<String,Tren>>conjunto=infoTrenes.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Tren>entrada:conjunto) {
            System.out.println("CLAVE: " + entrada.getKey() + "-> VALOR : " + entrada.getValue());
        }
        
        //infoTrenes.put("sfgsfdhdf",Tren);
         
        /* Hashtable<Integer,String>mapa=new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
         mapa.put(545342,"Roger Petrov");
         System.out.println(mapa);*/
      
        
        System.out.println(coleccion_vagones.toString());
        
        System.out.println(infoTrenes.toString());
        
        //Hashtable<String, Tren>ListaTrenes=new Hashtable<String, Tren>((Map<? extends String, ? extends Tren>) Arrays.asList(alta));
        
        
    
        

    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas deben incluir el error que encuentras cuando compilas o corres tu código. La traza de error. Así los demás no están mentalmente compilando código :) Por favor, inclúyela

Comment: Aunque existe, la clase Hashtable se considera obsoleta. usa HashMap en su lugar